# how to attach image from assets folder loaded in gallery view to email android?

Tags: android, assets

i'm new to android.
I have some images in assets folder.I know/and have already loaded them in a gallery view.

So my problem is :

when I open gallery,my images from assets folder gets loaded in gallery view.But when to send  it through email.It doesn't gets attached to email.I want them to get attached to email (one at a time) without saving them to Sd card.

can anyone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work with assets, but use  flag [Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) while launching the Email app.